# Different Ways to Turn a List into a Linked List Python 3

Tags: python, list, linked-list

I am wondering what is the difference between

```
def makeList(myList):
    head=None
    lst={}
    for value in myList:
        lst['data']=value
        lst['next']=head
        head=lst
    return head
```

and

```
def makeList(myList):
    head=None
    for value in myList:
        lst={}
        lst['data']=value
        lst['next']=head
        head=lst
    return head
```

Given `myList=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`, the first one returns `{'data':7,'next':(...)}` and the second one actually returns a linked list. This confuses me because I don't understand why I need to redefine `lst` as opposed to just overwriting the data.

Also, what does `(...)` mean?

Comment: run both and see the results. They are different.

Comment: The first one you create one `dict` and keep changing its contents.

Comment: @ Eugene Sh. As you can see at the bottom, I did run them. I am asking for an explanation as to why they are different.

Comment: Step through a debugger with the given code.

Comment: @khelwood Yes, but I'm wondering why I can't see the linked list and I just get 'next':(...)

Comment: A linked list involves a sequence of nodes, not just one node referring to itself. Creating one node and trying to put everything in it doesn't give you a linked list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the first example, consider what's happening. You have a dict assigned to `lst`. What `lst` refers to never changes -- it's *always* that same instance of a dict.

Every time you run through the loop, you are changing that single dict, overwriting the previous values.

When the loop completes, `head is lst` -- that is, they refer to the same object -- and, therefore, `head['next'] is head` -- it points to itself! No matter how fast your computer is or how big your screen is, printing out this recursive structure will overwhelm it. :-) Python uses `...` to indicate it's looping back to something already printed out.

The second example doesn't have this issue. Each time through the loop, you are creating a new instance of a dict and assigning it to `lst`; therefore, each instance of `lst` is now a new object, and `head` will only point to the last instance of `lst` created.

Comment: Thanks, @A. Grebenisan, for the edit suggestions! (And shame on me for missing an obvious typo!)

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you declare `lst = {}` once outside the loop, so `lst` is reused between iterations.

You get `d = {'data': 3, 'next': {...}}`. The ellipses (`...`) *usually* indicates a recursive reference.

You can confirm this by printing the `id` out:

```
In [1171]: id(d)
Out[1171]: 4456623368

In [1172]: id(d['next'])
Out[1172]: 4456623368
```

In the second case, you *redeclare* `lst` at each iteration, so you're safe.